# adding otf font resource for runtime only for inno setup

Tags: windows, winapi, fonts, inno-setup

I am trying to add some additional font type to resource and then use it in my inno setup installer, only for runtime, but it is not working for OTF Font types but works perfectly for TTF font types
the code I am using is something like that:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Application
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Application

[Files]
Source: Setup\Ubuntu.otf;  DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy

[code]
const
  FR_PRIVATE = $10;

function AddFontResourceEx(lpszFilename:string;fl:dword;pdv:integer): LongInt; external 'AddFontResourceExW@gdi32.dll stdcall';
function RemoveFontResourceEx(lpszFilename:string;fl:dword;pdv:integer): Boolean; external 'RemoveFontResourceExW@gdi32.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Ubuntu.otf');
  if (AddFontResourceEx(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Ubuntu.otf'),FR_PRIVATE,0) = 0) then
    MsgBox('failed adding font - Ubuntu.otf',mbInformation,MB_OK);
  result := true;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Font.Name := 'Ubuntu';
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  RemoveFontResourceEx(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Ubuntu.otf'),FR_PRIVATE,0);
end;
```

AddFontResourceEx function is always successful but there is no effect on font, it is using fail safe default font instead

Comment: *"it is not working for OTF Font"* - What is not working? Be specific! This is totally useless problem description. Does `AddFontResourceEx` fail? OR does it succeed, but changing font name of `WelcomeLabel1` fails? Or what?

Comment: @martin Prikryl No addfontresourceex doesn,t fail i had a check for that, check example, nor i think changing the font had failed, the msdn says addfontresource ex supports otf and it is successful also but don't know why it has no effect on label... I am too looking for what is problem...but thanks for having a look on this and also i check for multiple other otfs too

Comment: I've randomly piceked one .otf font: http://www.fontspace.com/burntilldead/steelworks-vintage-demo and I have no problems loading it using your code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEqrs.png - So it might be something specific about your font. Can we have copy of it for testing?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add Flag Parameter '[fontisnttruetype](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=FontInstall)'.